# Cucumber (rails 2) isn't loading jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara-webkit

I have a cucumber scenario tagged with `@javascript` and i'm testing it with some really basic inline js calls.  I'm running this using

Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit

If i do this on the page, after the element in question (which has id="ajax_test_results", don't worry about the ajax though, for now)

```
document.getElementById('ajax_test_results').innerHTML = 'Replaced with basic js, ie not jquery, without waiting for pageLoad';
```

then it works: if i render out the page in my test i can see that the js has run and updated the content.  However, if i try to do the same thing with jquery

```
jQuery("#ajax_test_results").html("updated with basic jquery dom manipulation, without waiting for document.ready");
```

then it doesn't work. I think that jquery isn't being loaded, but i don't know how to go about debugging it.

Any ideas anyone?  I saw this post which looked hopeful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428405/cucumber-tests-jquery-does-not-loaded-in-webdriver but `config.assets.debug = true` causes an error for me - i think it's rails 3 only.  Is there a rails 2 equivalent?  or some other solution?

Grateful for any advice - max

Comment: I have this same problem and it's not clear to me where you would tell cucumber to load jQuery.

Comment: Could it be that jquery is not loaded YET?

Comment: Seems obvious, but you might go about debugging it by calling `sleep` for a couple seconds in between when the page is rendered and you try to test for the element's presence

Answer (score 0):

For debugging you can use console.log('message') or alert statements. It will output your messages to the terminal screen. Also you can use:

```
Gemfile:
  gem 'debugger'

When /your step/ do
  require 'ruby-debug'
  debugger
end
```

then you can debug using page.evaluate_script or page.execute_script methods. It's quite easy to do it.

According jquery problem could you try to use $ instead of jQuery?

Alex.